# How to use k6 for lower/reduced bandwidth transfer speed testing scenarios

Tags: k6

I'm evaluating swapping some jmeter tests to k6, however I'm struggling to find this capability:

- Controlled/reduced bandwidth transfer capability (in jmeter world, characters per second)

Reference in jmeter land: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks

Is there such a capability with k6 and I'm just struggling to find it?

TIA!!!!